# Where is my program located that I run from command prompt

Tags: windows, windows-8, cmd.exe

I run command `svn` in command prompt and it works fine. Now I need to know where this executable located on my file system. How to know it?

Comment: Where it is located... in RAM? In the file system?

Comment: path in file system